# DHCP Relay Juniper on two EX2200

Tags: dhcp, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

I have a two EX2200 switches that are connected to each other using OSPF routing. One switch is configured as a dhcp server and gives out IP addresses to devices on local interfaces. I set up DHCP relay using bootp on the other switch, but I can't get addresses distributed to devices connected to this switch. I can ping the two l3 switches one from the other so OSPF is working. I am fairly new to networking and I was wondering, in broad terms, what needs to be done to the ports/vlans/etc on the switch to get it to request DHCP from the other switch. No code please, I'd like to learn on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Set up DHCP-Relay on switch 2 with your server (switch 1) IP address and reference each VLAN interface (eg: `vlan.x`) that you wish to relay for
2. Make sure you have a dedicated scope configured on switch 1 for each VLAN you will be serving and ensure that the gateway for each matches the appropriate `vlan.x` interface on switch 2